# ModalFilterPicker load more on scroll

Tags: jquery, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, reactive-programming

I am using "ModalFilterPicker" in my react native app. the problem is there is no load more option on scroll.
import { Component, View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
    import ModalFilterPicker from 'react-native-modal-filter-picker'
    export default class App extends Component {
      constructor (props, ctx) {
        super(props, ctx);
        this.state = {
          visible: false,
          picked: null,
        };
      }
      _loadMore() {
       console.log("load more")
    }
      render() {
        const { visible, picked } = this.state;

```
    const options = [
      {
        key: 'kenya',
        label: 'Kenya',
      },
      {
        key: 'uganda',
        label: 'Uganda',
      },
      {
        key: 'libya',
        label: 'Libya',
      },
      {
        key: 'morocco',
        label: 'Morocco',
      },
      {
        key: 'estonia',
        label: 'Estonia',
      },
    ];
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={this.onShow}>
          <Text>Select country</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>      
        <Text style={appStyles.label}>Selected:</Text>
        <Text>{picked}</Text>
        <ModalFilterPicker
          visible={visible}
          onSelect={this.onSelect}
          onCancel={this.onCancel}
          options={options}
         onEndReached={() => 
         this._loadMore()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
  onShow = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: true });
  }
  onSelect = (picked) => {
    this.setState({
      picked: picked,
      visible: false
    })
  }
  onCancel = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: false
    });
  }
}
```

but here the problem is it loads all the data at once, I need lazy-loading here, load 30 records first and then load other 30 records on scroll.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: No I am asking about, is there any feature which support load more option as like in listview